# How do I get my Text Boxes to stay exactly where I put them in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I get my Text Boxes to stay exactly where I put them in an Excel spreadsheet?

I have tried all the suggestions I have been given when I typed the sentence above into the Google search bar. I am using Windows 11 and MS Office 365. I get the text boxes into their exact positions along with arrows I have drawn from the text boxes to the different things on the spread sheet and every time I close the Excel file and then open it back up, the text boxes and the arrows have jumped to the left about an inch. The print in the text boxes stay in their original position, but the outer lines of the boxes and the arrows keep jumping over to the left about 1 inch.

How can I fix the text boxes in their original place where I had them before closing the file?

Answer (score 0):

- Right click your Text Box, click in Format Shape
- Shape Options >> Size and Properties >> Properties
- Select [Don't move or size with cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HymS3.png)